# Show Facebooks 'choose from photos' dialog in my application?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm writing an application for Facebook that allows the user to choose photos they want to associate with their post.  Is there a way I can use Facebook's 'Choose From Photos' dialog in my application?

I've look at the JavaScript SDK and didn't see it.  TIA

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to access the graph API and grab the user's photo, then build the UI yourself. I recommend jQuery UI dialog for these uses. It'S easy to use and looks great.